# PHP MYSQL and rewriteEngine for seo URLS

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

Hi I have a large property database but rather than using an url structure to display each property like :

www.mysite.com/d.php?ID=12345

I want to use

www.mysite.com/property-12345-Cyprus-Paphos-3-Bed-House-for-sale.php

Now I have stored the URL I want to use in the property database and I have this in my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^property-(.*).php$ ./d.php?ID=$i
```

Now the first part is working and the url rewrite is functioning as expected and the user is directed to

www.mysite.com/property-12345-Cyprus-Paphos-3-Bed-House-for-sale.php

But how do I get the property id from the url and then pass it to the page 
     d.php?   For example the 12345 ( But obviously this can be anthing ) I can change the structure of the url if I need to

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Aren't you better off using urls like `/property/12345/cyprus-Paphos-3-bed-house` ? That way you can use `explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])` and get all the parts in an array

Comment: I think you'd benefit from using slugs opposed to ids. By all means use ids but in this instance use a slug! Depending on your framework slugs are essentially a unique string on your table which you search for an exact match of. On creating a new instance of whatever it is you're slugging you create a new unique slug for that instance

Comment: Ha I never thought of that looks alot cleaner too - I will give it a go

Comment: Hi sourRaspberri . By Slugs to you mean /property/12345/cyprus etc like FMashiro suggested